# Running untrusted code in windows hyper-v containers

Tags: windows, security, docker, containers, hyper-v

It is mentioned on Microsoft Docs that containers provide isolation and security. Consider a scenario where an application accepts user code and runs it on server. So if we host the application on a hyper-v container on Windows server, then can we rest assured that whatever a user may write, it won't be able to affect our application's well being and the container which hosts it.

I have spent last week reading Microsoft docs on containers, but haven't yet found a direct answer to this query. Till now i have understood that our host OS will not be affected. Also that all the modifications made by the application will be captured ina sandbox, so our host OS is at almost no risk.

Answer (score 1):

Containers isolate an application with kernel name spacing. This means the applications will all share the same kernel and a kernel level exploit run inside a container could escape that container and impact the rest of the host. Docker allows various options to expose parts of the host to the container, so this will depend on how you run the container. And out of the box, docker does not have limits on utilization, so you can be DoS'd by an untrusted application.

Containers do provide more security than running everything outside of a container on the same host, but less security than if you spun up an entirely separate VM per app. You need to decide where on the security scale you need to be, and how much time and experience you have to lock down the kernel and container environment.

Comment: Hi thanks for the info. But what i was talking about was hyper-v containers, so there is no problem of sharing the kernel with the Host. Also my concern is well being of the application. So if i spun a VM and run the app inside it, then also my host will be safe in case of an attack, but application may go down. But since container image is immutable, i am confused that even if user write untrusted code, whether my application will run fine or not. DOS attacks are not something which i intend to prevent with containers. Only attacks by malicious code.

Comment: If you run the code in the same VM or namespace as your application, that code can take down your application. The more typical use case is to run untrusted code alone in it's own container. And malicious code may DoS attack your server, e.g. `:(){ :|: & };:` will bring down most hosts that have bash. Using all of your CPU, Memory, or any other resource like process ID's or stack space are all DoS attacks.

Comment: i have a mechanism that all the user entered codes will be automatically killed after 5 secs. So this is not a very big concern for us.I believe that any such code will have such effect for max 5 secs. Apart from this, can i believe that application is safe from all other attacks like deleting files, modifying registry etc. If application will continue to run in any case of there attacks, i believe that we will go ahead with hyper-v containers and will think a way for preventing DoS like own container for malicious code .....